# Pandas split weekly time series and groupby month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data set that contains weekly data but I need to calculate the average of it basis the weightage of the row if that week crosses the month. For example:

```
  Current_Week             Sales
0 29/Dec/2013-04/Jan/2014  3685.236419
1 05/Jan/2014-11/Jan/2014  3784.023564
2 12/Jan/2014-18/Jan/2014  3726.933727
3 19/Jan/2014-25/Jan/2014  3690.440944
4 26/Jan/2014-01/Feb/2014  3731.523630
5 02/Feb/2014-08/Feb/2014  3753.882783
6 09/Feb/2014-15/Feb/2014  3643.997381
7 16/Feb/2014-22/Feb/2014  3696.243919
8 23/Feb/2014-01/Mar/2014  3718.254426
```

Ultimately the desired output is:

```
Month       Sales
1-Jan-2014  3727.09
1-Feb-2014  3703.57
```

The thing to note is that for input dataframe at row 0, I need to calculate the `weightage` of `the number of days in that week for that month` so that it can be used to calculate the average of the sales later. For eg for month January

[image]

As you can see that, the monthly Sales for Jan is calculated from summing all the averaged sales and then divided by the number of weighted days: `16505.69 / 4.42 = 3727.09`

I know that I have to first the split the time series into two rows in the event the data crosses the month, and then `sum` them and `aggregate` them. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are weeks consecutive always?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, weeks are always consecutive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the weeks are consecutive, then we only need to concern about the starts of the weeks (as ends are starts + 1 day):

```
# get start and end dates of the weeks
time_df = df.Current_Week.str.split('-', expand=True)
time_df.columns = ['start','end']

# convert to datetime 
time_df = time_df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

# combine with original data
new_df = pd.concat((df, time_df), sort=False, axis=1)

# all the dates in range
all_dates = pd.date_range(new_df.start.iloc[0], new_df.end.iloc[-1], freq='D')

# set start as index for interpolate
new_df = (new_df[['Sales','start']]
            .set_index('start')
            .reindex(all_dates)  # resample to all dates
            .ffill()             # fill missing days
            .resample('MS')      # group over the month
            .mean()              # taking mean
     )
```

Output:

```
                  Sales
2013-12-01  3685.236419
2014-01-01  3727.092745
2014-02-01  3703.568527
2014-03-01  3718.254426
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly as what I need! I knew it would be easy with pandas, but I am stucked at splitting and stacking/unstacking. `.resample()` + `.mean()` is what I need

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm not sure I understand your comment. The answer was crafted to fit OP's expected output, which, I guess, is average **weekly** sales.

Answer (score 0):

**Month of sales and sum**

```
data.groupby('Month')['sales'].sum()
```